# How to change Any to Array in scala?

Tags: scala

```
scala> val arr = Array[Any](Array(1.0, 2.0))
arr: Array[Any] = Array(Array(1.0, 2.0))

scala> arr(0)
res28: Any = Array(1.0, 2.0)
```

The array `arr` is fixed. How to change `arr(0)` to `Array[Double]` in this situation?

Comment: don't force the return type to be any.

Comment: Inference as `Any` generally means something is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three options:

1) Don't cast to `Array[Any]` in the first place:

```
val arr: Array[Array[Double]] = Array(Array(1.0, 2.0))
val arr0: Array[Double] = arr(0)
```

2) Use `match`:

```
val arr0: Array[Double] = arr(0) match {
  case a: Array[Double] => a
}
```

3) Use `asInstanceOf`:

```
val arr0: Array[Double] = arr(0).asInstanceOf[Array[Double]]
```

These are in order of preference, with the option 1 being by far the best solution because it avoids throwing away type information.

Comment: I'd prefer 3 to 2 (with the caveat that they are both bad); 2 is just pointlessly longer and less efficient.